# Rewriting an arbitrary number of path segments to query parameters

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteRule viewshoplatest/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /viewshoplatest.php?$1=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10&$11=$12&$13=$14&$15=$16
```

It should map a URL like this:

```
http://www.veepiz.com/viewshoplatest/start/10/end/10/filter/0/ownerid/0/sortby/date/sortdir/DESC/cat/0/scat/0/
```

to this:

```
http://www.veepiz.com/viewshoplatest.php?start=0&end=10&filter=0&ownerid=0&sortby=date&sortdir=DESC&cat=0&scat=0
```

When I click on link and print `$_GET` variables I get this:

```
Array ( [start] => 10 [end] => 10 [filter] => 0 [ownerid] => 0 [sortby] => start0 [start1] => start2 [start3] => start4 [start5] => start6 )
```

Any ideas as to why it’s behaving badly?

---

Ok i have fixed this by rewriting the rule to

```
RewriteRule viewshoplatest/start/(.*)/end/(.*)/filter/(.*)/ownerid/(.*)/sortby/(.*)/sortdir/(.*)/cat/(.*)/scat/(.*)/$ /viewshoplatest.php?start=$1&end=$2&filter=$3&ownerid=$4&sortby=$5&sortdir=$6&cat=$7&scat=$8
```

Comment: looks to me like when it reaches above $9 it calls $1 for $10 and above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all: You shouldn’t use `.*` if you can be more specific, like in this case `[^/]+`. Because multiple `.*` can cause immense backtracking. So:

```
RewriteRule ^viewshoplatest/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /viewshoplatest.php?$1=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8&$9=$10&$11=$12&$13=$14&$15=$16
```

You can use a took like [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) to see the difference in how these regular expressions are processed.

But since mod_rewrite does only allow to reference the first nine groups (see [Tim’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655893/another-mod-rewrite-problem/3656017#3656017)), you could use an iterative approach and process one parameter at a time:

```
RewriteRule ^viewshoplatest/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+/[^/]+/.*)$ /viewshoplatest/$3?$1=$2 [QSA,N]
RewriteRule ^viewshoplatest/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]*)/?$ /viewshoplatest.php?$1=$2&$3 [QSA,L]
```

The first rule will process one parameter pair at a time (except the last pair) by append it to the already existing ones (see *QSA* flag) and then restart the rewriting process without incrementing the internal recursion counter (see *N* flag). The second rule will then rewrite the last parameter pair (or just the name) and end the iteration.

But since using the *N* flag might be dangerous as it can cause an infinite recursion, you could also use PHP to parse the requested path:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'] = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$segments = implode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI_PATH'], '/'));
array_shift($segments); // remove path prefix "/viewshoplatest"
for ($i=0, $n=count($segments); $i<$n; ) {
    $_GET[rawurldecode($segments[$i++])] = ($i < $n) ? rawurldecode($segments[$i++]) : null;
}
```

Now you just need this rule to pass the request through:

```
RewriteRule ^viewshoplatest(/|$) /viewshoplatest.php [L]
```

Comment: MINOR correction above: `explode()` the `REQUEST_URI_PATH`, not `implode()`. :)

Answer (score 3):

Just to expand on what you found out, you can only define nine groups to be used as backreferences, which is why it's generally a better idea to rewrite to a script sans-query string and have the script examine `REQUEST_URI` in cases where you will have a lot of data to parse out.

From [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> Back-references are identifiers of the
>   form $N  (N=0..9), which will be
>   replaced by the contents of the Nth
>   group of the matched Pattern

`$0` is the entire matched pattern, giving you the remaining nine numbers to work with. Any higher number is treated as a backreference followed by some literal numeric characters.