# $_Get not working in this particular case

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

I am trying to use 
`http://www.example.com/news/id/21/title/top-10-things/?page=`1 for sending the page parameter and it is not working in php

below is my setting in the .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /news.php?$1=$2&$3=$4
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/(.*)/$ /news.php?$1=$2
RewriteRule ^news/$ /news.php
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? `page` is not contained in `$_GET` or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try appending the `%{QUERY_STRING}` to the URLs in your htaccess.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /news.php?$1=$2&$3=$4&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/(.*)/$ /news.php?$1=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
RewriteRule ^news/$ /news.php&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

As Daniel noted, you can also use the mod_rewrite `qsappend` or `QSA` flag for this purpose. REF: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /news.php?$1=$2&$3=$4 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/(.*)/$ /news.php?$1=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^news/$ /news.php [QSA]
```

Comment: You can use the [QSA] (query string append) flag instead.

Answer (score 1):

Set the [*QSA* flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) to get the requested query automatically appended to the one in substitution URL:

```
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /news.php?$1=$2&$3=$4 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/(.*)/$ /news.php?$1=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^news/$ /news.php [QSA]
```

Furthermore, you shouldn’t use `.*` if you can be more specific. In this case using `[^/]+` instead avoids unnecessary backtracking:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /news.php?$1=$2&$3=$4 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /news.php?$1=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^news/$ /news.php [QSA]
```

And for a general solution for an arbitrary number or parameters, see [*Rewriting an arbitrary number of path segments to query parameters*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655893).