# osCommerce url rewrite

Tags: php, oscommerce

My osCommerce installation is forming the links like this:

`http://localhost/payment.php/test/ot_coupon`

Instead of this:
`http://localhost/payment.php?test=ot_coupon`

Is there any option to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Browse the [mod-rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite) tag for RewriteRule examples. See tag-wiki http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mod-rewrite/info and example answer 6 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655893/rewriting-an-arbitrary-number-of-path-segments-to-query-parameters#3683855

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell osCommerce to disable pretty url. Connect to admin panel, and click on "Configuration" menu.

There, you have 2 options depending of your version :

- look for the option called : `Use search-engine safe urls for all site links`. This is what you must disabled. Set it to `false`.
- go to module "SEO URLs" and disable the whole module.

Now OsCommerce should use the classic url schema.

Hope this helps!