# URLs with /12 instead of ?var=12

Tags: php, html, url-rewriting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to: URL re-writing in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1039725/how-to-url-re-writing-in-php)
>   [Rewriting an arbitrary number of path segments to query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655893/rewriting-an-arbitrary-number-of-path-segments-to-query-parameters)

Currently, on my website ([source world gaming](http://www.sourceworldgaming.com)), I use the $_GET method to display reviews/news articles. For example, "sourceworldgaming.com/reviews.php?id=40" will display review #40 in the database.

IGN doesn't do this. For example, they use http://www.ign.com/games/guild-wars-2/pc-896298 - with no $_GET[] needed. How is this done? Do they create an index for each individual game?

I want to be able to make the URL sourceworldgaming.com/reviews.php/40

Also, would doing this make my site more search engine friendly? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure exactly how they are doing it, but in general, [mod_rewrite (or similar)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is your friend.

Comment: @mario dup of MANY a questions here. A little tip the the OP they are called pretty URLS

Answer (score 2):

Its done with mod_rewrite and the router part of the script:

The url: `http://www.example.com/games/guild-wars-2/pc-896298`

Is actually passed to the script like:

`http://www.example.com/?route=/games/guild-wars-2/pc-896298`

By using mod_rewrite (example)

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then basically `/games/guild-wars-2/pc-896298` is split up into pieces using

`$route = explode('/',$_GET['route'])`

So `$route[0]` would be the controller or query the categories. 
   `$route[1]` would be the action or query the game because `$route[0]` is a game category ect

Answer (score 0):

The fact that requests for `/foo.php` go to a file named `foo.php` on your server is just an implementation detail.  There's nothing about the web that requires this, it's just something that a lot of systems do, including PHP.  Lots of other systems use different conventions, such as routing tables or object traversal.

If you've already built a website that uses the file system to route requests, the easiest way of getting different URLs is to use mod_rewrite or its equivalent on whichever web server software you use.