# rewrite to friendly urls php

Tags: php, .htaccess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rewriting an arbitrary number of path segments to query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655893/rewriting-an-arbitrary-number-of-path-segments-to-query-parameters)

htaccess` rewrite but im not sure on how to rewrite multiple address gets

I developed a forum from scratch and would like to change

`url = view_topic.php?cat=$cat&sub=$sub&tid=$tid`

to say

`view_topic.php?catname/subname/topicname`

some help would be great

Comment: If you're going to rewrite urls, might as well get rid of that ugly `view_topic.php?` part too.

Comment: so maybe forums/catname/subname/topicname

Comment: Have you used our search function? This question comes up hourly. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/mod-rewrite/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^viewtopic/([a-z])/([a-z])/([a-z])$ viewtopic.php?cat=$1&sub=$2&tid=$3 [NC,L]
```