# Replace URL /gallery/art/paris with PHP parameters?

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rewriting an arbitrary number of path segments to query parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655893/rewriting-an-arbitrary-number-of-path-segments-to-query-parameters)

I'm sure this has been asked many times but I don't actually know what it is I'm searching for, so if someone could just point me to the correct place that would be brilliant.

Basically, I have a page "gallery.php" which at the moment loads images from directories (first part is hard coded) then in the url you'd type ?a=art/paris, so the full URL is `gallery.php?a=art/gallery`.

Is there a way I can modify apache and/or my php code so the user can type in `/gallery/art/paris/` or `/gallery/art/paris` and get the same result? (anything after /gallery/ is the one parameter I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting this in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-F

RewriteRule ^gallery/([a-z-A-Z0-9\/]+)$ /gallery.php?a=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: That's almost what I need but it doesn't work with /art/paris. It only passes /art as the parameter. I need it to pass /art/paris as the parameter.

Comment: (1) Those three RewriteCond make it slower and are unnecessary. (2) it will also cause /art/gallery/foo/bar/temp/test/whatever to also work. (3) a lot of duplicate content issues with this one.

Comment: By all means, correct my answer :), it'll in turn provide a great answer for future visitors on this page.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to do that. What you need is `mod_rewrite` installed and activated on your Apache server. Then create a `.htaccess` file, in which you can "tell" Apache which URLs to rewrite and specify the rules how to be done. So basically you'd need something like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ gallery.php?a=$1/$2 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what your looking for?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/\.]+) gallery.php?a=$1 [L]
```

or you could be more specific:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^gallery/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+) gallery.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L]
```