# Rewrite .htaccess URL variable rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently use:

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f 
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
```

for removing `.php` and `.html`.

But I was wondering how would I rewrite `?[variableName]=[variable]`.

So for example, currently this happens:

`http://myurl.com/about.html` to `http://myurl.com/about/`

But how would I then rewrite variables such as:

`http://myurl.com/foo/?bar=true` to `http://myurl.com/foo/bar/true/`

*or is this not possible?*

Thanks for your help, any optimizations on my current rewrite is also welcome!

EDIT: Hi All, so after some help from zx, I have gotten to this:

```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]

   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ([^=]+)=([^=]+)
   RewriteRule ^/?$ %1/%2?  [L,R]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
```

And I link like: `href="./?do=foo"` and the return is `/?do=foo` **not** `/do/foo/`.

Here is a pastebin to 100% of the .htaccess code, including the stuff in there which was default from the host provider: [click](http://pastebin.com/TmV4a0Tt)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rewriting an arbitrary number of path segments to query parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655893/rewriting-an-arbitrary-number-of-path-segments-to-query-parameters)

Comment: @Sumurai8 - Although you have flagged this question for being a duplicate, it seems they have an understanding of regex. Their way of writing the answer and explaining it DOESN'T help me at all. Thats why I created this... Hoping for a basic, decent answer.

Comment: If you ask a regex-related question, you are expected to have a basic understanding of regex. If you don't, then go get a basic understanding of regex. The regex used in mod_rewrite is similar to PCRE and what PHP uses.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting confused about which way we're going, so here are two options.

**Option 1**

Link entered by user: `something?do=foo`

Rewritten link: `do/foo`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ([^=]+)=([^=]+)
RewriteRule ^/?$ %1/%2?  [L,R]
```

**Option 2**

Link entered by user: `foo/bar/true`

Rewritten link: `foo/bar=true`

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1?$2=$3 [QSA,DPI,L,R]
```

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- Each `([^/]+)` matches a path fragment and captures it to one of the Groups
- `/?` matches an optional final slash
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string
- `$1?$2=$3` uses the Group captures to rewrite the url
- `QSA` appends any pre-existing paremeters
- `DPI` discards any path fragments
- `L` tells mod-rewrite to stop examining rules after this one

Comment: @Sumurai8 You're right! I keep reading the questions literally. :) Thanks for pointing that out, I'll have another look.

Comment: Apparently I had in reverse... Updated the rule, please try again. :)

Comment: No, just the opposite... I switched it around because @Sumurai8 told me I had it in reverse!

Comment: `href="./?do=foo"` gives 404 :( This is a pain, aha

Comment: Okay, look at option 1.

Comment: I have edited the original question, for some reason - I am attempting to do option 1, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I guess it doesn't show these comments within your tracker?