# How can change url link with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have PHP file `page.php`, and with this file I dynamically change content. So how can I make with htaccess to change link from `www.example.com/page.php?page=somepage` to `www.example.com/somepage`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rewriting an arbitrary number of path segments to query parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655893/rewriting-an-arbitrary-number-of-path-segments-to-query-parameters)

Comment: Note that you don't change a URL _from_ `/page.php?page=somepage` to `/somepage` in .htaccess. This is something you do in your application. However, you can implement an external redirect to handle _old_ URLs if you wish. What you do do in .htaccess is _internally rewrite_ the request from `/somepage` to `/page.php?page=somepage` (ie. the other way round) - as Starkeen has covered in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /page.php?pape=$1 [NC,L]
```

This will rewrite your url

```
 example.come/somepage
```

to

```
 example.come/page.php?page=somepage
```