# RegEx htaccess - Get each part of URL pathname

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I'd like to create a RewriteRule to get each part of a pathname URL.

Here is a sample example:

Let's say I call this URL :

> 127.0.0.1/service/param1/param2/param3/param4/param5/param6

I would like to transform this call by this one :

> 127.0.0.1/index.php?s=service&p_1=param1&p_2=param2&p_3=param3&p_4=param4&p_5=param5&pa_6=param6

I tried a lot of different RegEx but whithout success unfortunately.

Here is the one I was a lot confident about but it fails

```
RewriteRule ^(str)[/]?(.*)[/]?(.*)[/]?(.*)[/]?(.*)[/]?(.*)[/]?(.*)$ /index.php?s=$1&p_1=$2&p_2=$3&p_3=$4&p_4=$5&p_5=$6&p_6=$7 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Any help would be very appreciate !

Comment: Are these parameters optional?

Comment: Almost sure there is no such option, but you could easily do this with PHP. Just RewriteRule everything to the `index.php` file, and inside that php file do the splitting

Comment: You have no `str` in your URL. `(service)[/]?(.*)[/]?(.*)[/]?(.*)[/]?(.*)[/]?(.*)[/]?(.*)$` should do it. The `/` also doesnt need to be in a character class and you probably want to require the `/`s and value between. e.g. `(service)/(.+?)/(.+?)/(.+?)/(.+?)/(.+?)/(.*)$`.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Yes, there are.

Comment: @chris85 I'm going to try it out ! Thanks !

Comment: @chris85 After try, I think your regex can work if parameters are not optional. but in my case, we should be able to call `127.0.0.1/service/param1` and also `127.0.0.1/service/param1/param2/param3` or `127.0.0.1/service` :-)

Comment: @Dekel Well, I have found this `^(service)(?:/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+))?(?:/([^/]+))?)?/?$` which is working but only if I have less than 4 parameters. 
But I try to understand this regex without success ahah !

Comment: If you know the number of parameters - it's ok. If you don't know the number - I don't think you will be able to do this with htaccess regex

Comment: Why not do this with PHP?

Comment: Well it was working with htaccess (following the regex I gave previously) that why I tried. And it's really simple to use $_REQUEST after.
One thing important that I didn't ask about, is that I know the maximum of parameters that can be passed. 
In my case, I can have 6 parameters maximum.

Comment: Your going to write extra parameters if the groups are optional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your parameters are optional, you want to make the whole capture groups optional, not just your slashes. To accomplish this we can use non-capturing groups.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/([^/]*))?(?:/([^/]*))?(?:/([^/]*))?(?:/([^/]*))?(?:/([^/]*))?(?:/([^/]*))?(?:/([^/]*))?$ /index.php?service=$1&p1=$2&p2=$3&p3=$4&p4=$5&p5=$6&p6=$7&p7=$8 [L]
```

`([^/]+)` captures the service. It is not optional, and should always be there. The `[^/]` part matches a character that is not a slash... and we match at least one, and as much as we can. Then we use groups of `(?:/([^/]*))?` to capture each argument. The `?:` syntax marks a group as non-capturing. The contents will not be used for the `$x` replacement strings. The `?` behind the whole non-capturing group makes it an optional argument. The inner capture group will be used for the replacement later on. All replacement strings are replaced by something. If nothing is matched for a particular replacement group, it is replaced by the empty string.

An url like `http://example.com/service/param1/param2/param3/` will result in an url as `http://example.com/index.php?service=service&p1=param1&p2=param2&p3=param3&p4=&p5=&p6=&p7=`.

If you want to match more than 8 optional parameters, you are better off passing the request on to a php router. If you have key-value pairs as path segments, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655893/rewriting-an-arbitrary-number-of-path-segments-to-query-parameters#3683855) may help you.

Comment: Thanks man ! I got it ! 
Appreciate the explanation of the regex by the way.