# Rewrite path segments with name value pairs to query parameters

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pretty-urls

I want to rewrite pretty urls to a query parameter in my .htaccess file using regex.

So that:

```
https://www.example.com/s/file/name1/value1/name2/value2/name3/value3
```

gets rewritten to:

```
https://www.example.com?file.htm?name1=value1&name2=value2&name3=value3
```

It needs to handle variable numbers of name pair values. It will include at least one name value pair. Eg it needs to work with `https://www.example.com/s/file/name1/value1` and `https://www.example.com/s/file/name1/value1/name2/value2`

The `s` in `https://www.example.com/s/file/name1/value1/name2/value2/name3/value3` indicates the rewrite rule should trigger: all other urls should be left alone. The `file` value is the name of the htm file, so this can have different values.

In [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gP6oDI/1) I have tried:

- pattern: `\/([^\/]+)(\/)([^\/]+)`
- substitution: `$1=$3&`
- On string: `/s/new/v/123/c/42`
- And it returns: `s=new&v=123&c=42&`

But it should return: `new.htm?v=123&c=42`

So I have successfully gotten it to work with a variable number of name value pairs. But I just can't get my head around how to make it first move past `s` and `new` and then dynamically replace name value pairs.

I did not include `https://www.example.com/` in regex101 because in a .htaccess file the initial domain is assumed.

I found [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655893/rewriting-an-arbitrary-number-of-path-segments-to-query-parameters) but it seems to work with a fixed amount of value pairs.

I also reviewed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained) which contains great information, but no solution to this specific issue.

Comment: You won't be able to do this with a regular expression in a RewriteCond.  
You have to use `RewriteMap` and a custom perl ou python script.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/rewrite/rewritemap.html#prg

Answer (score 0):

In the end I simplified what I needed. In the htaccess file I put:

```
RewriteRule ^v/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /voucher/$1.htm?v=$2 [NC,R,L]
```

So now a pretty url that looks like

```
https://www.example.com/v/page/id
```

gets rewritten to

```
https://www.example.com/voucher/page.htm?v=id
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer, could you please do let me know if your url is same levels in terms of `/` in your shown samples `https://www.example.com/s/file/name1/value1/name2/value2/name3/value3` then I could try to write it here, cheers.